# Jquery Dynamic property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$('.myClass')[0].src += "somethinghere";
```

And I also have multiple Div's with myClass.

How can I have the [0] to by relevant to the selected Div?

For example:

```
$('.myClass')[this].src += "somethinghere";
```

Here is the js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(document).on("mouseover",".myClass",function(){

        //code here

        });      

});
```

The HTML is :

```
<div>
   <a class="myLinkClass" href="" target="_blank">Hover Here</a>
   <div class="box">
   <iframe class="myIframeClass" width="260" height="150" src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
   <a class="myLinkClass" href="" target="_blank">Hover Here</a>
   <div class="box">
   <iframe class="myIframeClass" width="260" height="150" src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
   <a class="myLinkClass" href="" target="_blank">Hover Here</a>
   <div class="box">
   <iframe class="myIframeClass" width="260" height="150" src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

What seems to work everytime is:

```
$('.myIframeClass')[0].src += "something";
```

but it will only work for the first iframe and not for the others

Comment: what do `this` refers to? you should share relevant markup and JS.

Comment: is this running in a `click` handler ? if so post the selector of the `.click` handler.

Comment: Added js to the question

Comment: `this` would be the element the handler was triggered on, however, it sounds like they're `div` elements, which don't have a `src` property

Comment: @billyonecan, You could make it as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `this` directly
***update***: after the updated answer (with the real html) it turns out you need to use the `closest` method to find the container `div` and then the `.find` to locate the actual `iframe`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("mouseover", ".myLinkClass", function() {
    var iframe = $(this).closest('div').find('iframe').get(0);
    iframe.src += 'something%20';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <a class="myLinkClass" href="" target="_blank">Hover Here</a>
  <div class="box">
    <iframe class="myIframeClass" width="260" height="150" src="http://urlecho.appspot.com/echo?body=frame-1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <a class="myLinkClass" href="" target="_blank">Hover Here</a>
  <div class="box">
    <iframe class="myIframeClass" width="260" height="150" src="http://urlecho.appspot.com/echo?body=frame-2" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <a class="myLinkClass" href="" target="_blank">Hover Here</a>
  <div class="box">
    <iframe class="myIframeClass" width="260" height="150" src="http://urlecho.appspot.com/echo?body=frame-3" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Keep in mind that `div` elements do not have a `src` property.

If they are indeed `div` elements you might want to use the `.attr` method instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on("mouseover",".myClass",function() {
           var element = $(this),
               currentSrc = $(this).attr('src');

           element.attr('src', currentSrc + 'something');
        });      
});
```

Comment: @estevangomez then the first version should work. Although it will keep adding the `'something'` on each mouseover.

Comment: @estevangomez i am using what you posted only. You have put the `myClass` on the `iframe` in the html you posted in your question. Post the actual html if you want our answers to work for it. We cannot guess the html you use :)

Comment: @estevangomez you are not closing the inner `div` in your html.